# Excel VBA - Unchecking a text filter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a script to apply a filter to a particular column in excel, and then uncheck one of the text filters. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **macro vba recorder** to build a sample version of what you're trying to do and then adapt the code.

You can also have a look [**here**](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba.htm).

Comment: Holy!! I totally forgot about recording macros. perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than unchecking a filter you need specify all the ones you *do* want eg

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$D$21").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("1", _
    "12", "2", "22", "4", "5", "6", "8"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Okay, so I can't just add code to uncheck one particular text filter, like so? http://kusfaw0a.fs.utc.com/sites/CMS%20Training/Publishing%20Site/Dan%20Turcotte/webparts/Documents/VBA%20Uncheck%20Filter.JPG